# iOS 15 > Angular 13 > PWA > "Cold Launch" in Airplane Mode shows "Safari cannot open the page because your iPhone is not connected to the internet."

Tags: angular, safari, progressive-web-apps, mobile-safari, service-worker

Technology:

1. iPhone 12
2. iOS 15.0.1
3. Angular 13
4. PWA

Steps to reproduce:

1. Navigate to website in Safari
2. Tap 'Share', then 'Add to Home Screen'
3. Launch the web app and Log In
4. Use the app for a little bit
5. Close the app
6. Engage airplane mode
7. Launch the web app
8. If bug presents, will see "Safari cannot open the page because your iPhone is not connected to the internet."

Important notes:

- It is STILL possible to get the app to properly load, given the following steps AFTER Steps 1-8 above

1. Hit 'refresh' button
2. Swipe right to back-navigate
3. Observe that the app has successfully loaded

- The app is using scope '/'
- The app is using start_url '/abc/def/index.html'
- The app is using baseHref '/abc/def/'
- The page located at start_url is guarded by authentication, and will redirect to login page if not authenticated
- In steps 1-8, we logged in